# How to add 2 myFunctions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have added a myFunction code to my site. No problem, it works. Then I tried to add a second myFunction. The problem is, if I ad a second myFunction it doesn't work. It will only run succesfully when I use 1 myFunction. I tried everything to do, changed the name (myFunction2), people said me to do that but it doesn't work.
My question is now: How to add 2 myFunctions?

Script 1:

```
    var myVar;
function myFunction(loader) {
    myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}
function showPage(loader) {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

Script 2:

```
window.onscroll = function(scroller) {myFunction(scroller)};

function myFunction(scroller) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 550 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 550) {
        document.getElementById("content").className = "slideUp";
    }
}
```

Comment: Every function should be unique. Try this to learn the basics https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_return

Comment: Post (using [Edit]) the code that gives you a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function UniqueFunctionName(parameters){
    //put code here
}
UniqueFunctionName(startparameters); //not necessary
```

That is how to make a function.

```
function AnotherFunctionName(parameters){
    //put code here
}
AnotherFunctionName(startparameters); //not necessary
```

That is how to make another function.
In your case this should be:

```
function myFunction1(){
    //code in here
}

function myFunction2(){
    //code in here
}
myFunction1(); // or not
myFunction2(); // or not
```

If it is like that the the specific code in the function needs to be debugged.

From what you have said i think that you just need to debug the code.

http://five.agency/javascript-debugging-for-dummies/

Learn to find and remove mistakes in your code and all will be easier.

If the code is flawless then the only other possibility is that it is not called.

To test for that insert this code like so:

```
function myFunction2(){
    console.log('The function loads!');
    //put code here
    console.log('The function works!');
}
```

Save the code and open the webpage.

Open a debugger and search for the console.

If you see both messages then the code does not work the way it is expected.

If you see the first message and an error message then the code NEEDS debugging.

If you see neither messages then the code does not even load and you need to debug the input mechanisms/setInterval/setTimeout and/or parameters depending on the error message. If you have no input mechanisms/setInterval/setTimeout then add one or call the function directly from the code like shown in most of my code blocks above otherwise the code will never EVER load.

EDIT: parameter scroller is not defined. change 'function(scroller) {myFunction(scroller)};' to 'function(){myFunction2()};' and 'function myFunction(scroller) {' to 'function myFunction2(){'

Comment: Thank you soo much. I was thinking it will never run good, but finally..... Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than one function with the same name. Try changing the second script to myScrollerFunction and when you call it, change it to myScrollerFunction as well.

No two functions can share the same name.